# How can I create a progress-bar using PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, progress-bar

I am using PHP and JavaScript in my application.

I want to delete entries from the database, a process which requires a significant amount of time, thus I would like to report the progress to the end-user.

I'd like to know how to achieve this, could anyone explain the theory to me?

Comment: show some code ! what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 scripts:

- First for delete
- Second for status

First make a request to the first script, and then make a second request to the second script that will report you a progress.

Then you can use any of the jQuery plugin to display the progress bar.

Comment: can u give me a breif intoduction to 2nd script which will report status